# How do you pronunce "il a fait une erreur"?

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

I did just hear "il a fait une erreur" and I thought it was pronounced as:

```
Il a fet une erreur
```

But the voice I hear is:

```
Il a finerreur
```

Why does `fait` become `fin` in my ears?

Comment: You don't have to put the /t/ on *fait* ... it's an optional liaison. So the /n/ you're hearing comes from *une*. And in fast speech, the vowels might get slurred together, or one could be dropped.

Comment: @PeterShor So it's OK to say `il a fet un-erreur` here?`

Comment: It's okay. That's what optional (*liaison facultative*) means.

Comment: @PeterShor So some people drop the `t` in `fait` and some don't?

Comment: @PeterShor So what do you think is the most correct way to pronunce `il a fait une erreur`? I think `il a fet unerreur` have a very smooth way.

Comment: They're both correct. You'd have to ask a native French speaker which is more common (and that is going to depend on what part of France they're from, and how formal a situation they're in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common pronunciations in France are:

[ilafɛ ynɛʁœʁ] (ilafè unèreur)

and

[ilafe yneʁœʁ] (ilafé unéreur)

The liaison is possible [ilafɛtynɛʁœʁ] (ilafètunèreur) but extremely rare in casual French and still uncommon in formal French. An exception would be a French language teacher providing hints to schoolchildren during a *dictée*.

When the sentence is spoken quickly, the initial **I** can be slightly or significantly dropped and the **U** can be soften and often turned into a "schwa".

[lafɛənɛʁœʁ]

This seems to be what your heard as "Il a finerreur".

Comment: I think the pronunciation [fɛ]  for "fait" is still considered (for now) as the standard pronunciation (that is the one given by dictionaries), and [fe] a regional variation - although very widespread (from my experience, even definitely the most common one in Southern France).

Comment: @Greg Dictionaries just happen to almost exclusively report the "educated" Parisian/TV/Radio pronunciation.  *MASCARILLE.- Pour moi, je tiens que hors de Paris, il n’y a point de salut pour les honnêtes gens.* Molière, *Les précieuses ridicules*, 1659. Paris is, as far as linguistics are concerned, just another region.

Comment: @jiliagre: totally agree, and no judgment of value on any so-called regional variations. I just wanted to point it out as the OP seems to be a non-native learner, and I expect the standard pronunciation [fɛ] is what is taught to such learners, so it might be a bit surprising to come across [fe].  But I could even bet that [fe] will become the prevalent pronunciation in a couple of decades.

Comment: @Greg I might have not point this distinction in my reply because it often doesn't matter a lot. Spanish phonology only list /e/ as and rarely report /ɛ/ usage, even while it sometimes exists. Most English variants do not care that much either about whether to report /ɛ/ vs /e/. See http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/03/more-about-e-and.html . This seems to apply to Swedish too according to this statement found on the Swedish phonology Wikipedia page: *In many central and eastern areas (including Stockholm), the contrast between short /ɛ/ and /e/ is lost*.

Comment: Maybe I am influenced by my Belgian background where the opposition /ɛ/ vs. /e/ is still more vivid than in other regions, as for other phonemes (I had a funny experience years ago, when a French guest speaker came to my university in Brussels, and in a lecture kept on hammering "qui sait ?", " qui sait ?", and it took a moment for all Belgian students to understand he did not mean "qui c'est ?")

Comment: See also this interesting article, the opposition is still perceived by speakers in some regions of France, eg in piqué vs piquet : https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/07/06/ces-mots-qui-ne-se-prononcent-pas-de-la-meme-facon-dun-bout-a-lautre-de-la-france/

Comment: @Greg Yes. It's always easier to accept something as a standard when we happen to comply with and care of it. I have that kind of feeling when still supporting the in/un distinction that used to be the norm in all French speaking locations but that has mostly disappeared from the "français standard" and a large part of France except the former occitan area.